# Iterating through and displaying an attribute of an element of a list

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, jstl

So - this seems like a simple question, and its really probably an order-of-operations-ish question.

I have a list of objects titled "RequirementsList". Each element of the list is a "Requirements" object, with an attribute "environment". I just want to iterate through the list and display all of the attributes.

My code thus far:

```
<core:forEach var="record" items="${recordModel.requirementsList}" varStatus="outer">
    <tr>
        <td> requirementsList[${outer.index}].environment</td>
    </tr>
<core:forEach>
```

I've tried various combinations of double quotes and $s, but the issue (I think) is that, I need to encapsulate the entire thing in a ${} for it to bind to the model, but also, the outer.index needs to be evaluated and placed within that. How can I do both? Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding,as you said "I just want to iterate through the list and display all of the attributes" I think this is what you are trying to display ?

**somefile.java**

```
List<Record> recordList = new ArrayList<Record>();
Record record = new Record();
record.setEnvironment("Env1");
Record record1 = new Record();
record1.setEnvironment("Env2");
Record record2 = new Record();
record2.setEnvironment("Env3");

recordList.add(record);
recordList.add(record1);
recordList.add(record2);
```

to display these list of records in the jsp page, you can simply use

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page session="false"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>


    <c:forEach var="record" items="${records}" varStatus="outer">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${record.environment}"/></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>

</body>
</html>
```

The output will be

```
Env1 Env2 Env3
```

Let me know if this what you need.

Comment: Oi. Yes. It appears so. This is a clear case of me having stared at it for too long and missing the obvious solution. Thanks for jogging my memory! I'd totally just missed that you can use "record" (in this case) as the iterating variable. Not enough rep. to upvote, but I've accepted your answer!